# document.write not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I'm creating a shopping cart using html and js. I'm using document.write to return the values of the cart.

Firefox and IE display this correctly, but in Chrome the fields are blank. Any idea why this could be?

On page 1 the user adds items to the cart. This works fine. But when the information is sent to my 2nd page where users can add their checkout information the cart information is lost in Chrome (but not Firefox or IE).

Below is the code of the shopping cart on page 2 - could the problem lie in here?:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td><p>Quantity</p></td>
    <td><p>Item</p></td>
    <td><p>Unit Cost</p></td>
    <td><p>Total Cost</p></td>
</tr>


<script>
var numitems = opener.numitems;
var totcost = 0;

for (i=1; i<=numitems; i++)
{
    if(opener.items[i] != null)
    {
        if(opener.items[i].M_quantity > 0)
    {

        document.write("<tr><td><p style=text-align:center>" + opener.items[i].M_quantity);
        document.write("</p></td><td><p style=text-align:center>" + opener.items[i].M_desc);
        document.write("</p></td><td><p style=text-align:center>" + opener.items[i].M_price);
        cost = opener.items[i].M_price * opener.items[i].M_quantity;
        totcost += cost;
        totcost2 = totcost;
        document.write("</p></td><td><p style=text-align:center>" + cost);
        document.write("</p></td></tr>\n");
        // hidden fields for returning in callback
        document.write("<input type=hidden name='M_qty" + i + "'");
        document.write(" value='" + opener.items[i].M_quantity + "'>\n");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name='M_desc" + i + "'");
        document.write(" value='" + opener.items[i].M_desc + "'>\n");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name='M_price" + i + "'");
        document.write(" value='" + opener.items[i].M_price + "'>\n");

        }
    }
}

document.write("<tr><td colspan=3><b><p>Total Cost:</p></b>");
totcost = opener.roundOff(totcost,2);
document.write("</td><td><p style=text-align:center><b>&pound;" + totcost + "</b></td></tr>");
</script>

</table>
```

Comment: Add your code also in your post?

Comment: how is `opener` defined? is `opener.items` and array `opener.numitems` long? if so, your code will skip the first item, and try to output an undefined item. However, none of this should prevent `document.write` from outputting at least some of the rows. i would highly recommend learning alternatives to the ancient and ridiculous document.write

Comment: None of the rows are returned so I believe the problem may lie with document.write. The code was supplied by a payment company (I have been trying to bring it into the 21st century by removing frames and as many tables as possible).

Comment: This is now resolved - the problem occurs when working locally. When live the issue is fixed. In any case I will look to refrain from using document.write.